# Writing on a CSV file a MS Access Table in Java

Tags: java, mysql, csv, ms-access, datatable

I'm writing a little software that automatically exports a table called "Magazzino" of a .mdb file to a csv file. Everything works fine and I wrote this code using "UCANACCESS" library.

```
package it.simonesaleri.automation.software;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AutomationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            
            //OPENING CONNECTION TO DATABASE
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://eCommerce.mdb");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("eCommerce.csv");
            System.out.println("Connection to Database");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            
            //SQL INJECT CODE
            String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Magazzino";
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sqlString);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
                    arr.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
            }
            //SAVING INTO THE FILE
            for(String str: arr)
            {
                writer.append(str);
                writer.append(";");
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm having an issue...I don't really understand how to create a new line on the .csv file while writing on it. I tried to `.append("\n")` or `.append("\r\n")`, but the results is this:

```
1;244;300817; BA9S - 220R  LAMPADA LED 220VAC  ROSSA;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;12.14;3.6420000000000003;5.6451;5.463000000000001;5.098800000000001;4.7346;5.88183;PCE;22.0;IVA 22%;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;;731;CHINT;CHT;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;CHTCHTAUTOM-A01;;;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;null;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;0;0;2;9713;BSD450B/8A; CONVERTITORE BRUSHLESS FD BSD450B/8A;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;680.0;680.0;1054.0;1020.0;952.0;884.0;1098.2;;22.0;IVA 22%;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;;;;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;null;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;0;0;
```

Instead of this (result that I need):

```
1;244;300817; BA9S - 220R  LAMPADA LED 220VAC  ROSSA;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;12.14;3.6420000000000003;5.6451;5.463000000000001;5.098800000000001;4.7346;5.88183;PCE;22.0;IVA 22%;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;;731;CHINT;CHT;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;CHTCHTAUTOM-A01;;;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;null;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;0;0;
2;9713;BSD450B/8A; CONVERTITORE BRUSHLESS FD BSD450B/8A;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;680.0;680.0;1054.0;1020.0;952.0;884.0;1098.2;;22.0;IVA 22%;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;0;null;null;;;;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;null;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;FALSE;FALSE;0;0;
```

Comment: I don't see where in your code you do ` .append("\n")`

Comment: You can't put line separators into csv unless the fields are quoted. I suggest you use a proper csv library. Also your code will miss the last column. It should be `<=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way I suppose:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while (rs.next()) {
    // Clear StringBuilder object in prep for a new CSV line
    sb.setLength(0); 
    // Create custom CSV data line using semicolon (;) as delimiter...
    for (int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++) {
        /* IF StringBuilder is not empty then add a semicolon
           to the end of the last piece of columnar data that 
           was appended before appending this next piece of 
           columnar data.            */
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append(rs.getString(i));
    }
    // Add the system newline character to custom CSV data line.
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator()); 
    // Add the newly created CSV line to the ArrayList.
    arr.add(sb.toString());
}
   
    
// Write to File...
for(String str: arr) {
    /* str already has the newline character appended 
       to it from the process above.  */
    writer.append(str); 
    // immediate write:
    writer.flush(); 
}
writer.close(); // Close the writer.
```